# ssh-based (SOCKS5) password proxy

Tags: proxy, passwords, openssh, socks5

I'd like to share to a friend an access to the intranet of a place because he forgot his password. I was thinking to use on a server of mine `ssh -D '*:1080' me@intranet.com`, and then let my friend connect to my server on port 1080 to forward him to the intranet. However I'm affraid to let the door open to some crazy bots. That's why I'd like to add a password, but it appears that ssh does not support SOCKS5 passwords…

I tried to see if netcat or nginx could help me by adding an intermediate step between my friend and ssh but for now I found no easy solution as netcat does not support SOCKS5 password server mode either…

Note that I'd like a "secure" solution if possible that does not send the password in cleartext, and also I don't want to install anything on intranet's side.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, this script runs on the server, because I don't have access to my friend's computer. So my friend would connect to my server on port 1080, and then he is forwarded to the intranet.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit, thanks @KamilMaciorowski